# When copying formulas, Application error when equal sign

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub NewFormula()
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim str(130), str1, str2, strL, str3, z, con1, con2, con3, conL As Variant
    Dim stri, a, b As Integer
    Dim np, equ As Variant
    equ = "="
    np = "'C:\Document..."
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Docus"
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Docus").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    str(i) = Worksheets("Docus").Cells(i, 5).Formula
    stri = InStr(str(i), "+")
    If Not (Worksheets("Docus").Cells(i, 5).Formula) = isBlank Then
    If Not (Worksheets("Docus").Cells(i, 5).Formula) = "=E*" Then
    
    a = Len(str(i))
    b = InStr(1, str(i), "]")
    z = Right(str(i), a - b)
    
    'It gives error exactly here.
    'Application-defined or object defined error

    Worksheets("Docus").Cells(i, 5).Formula = equ & np & z
    '...I think to continue writing code is unnecessary

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `"=E*"` doesn't look like a valid formula. Main note: what does `Debug.Print equ & np & z` return in the Immediate Window?

Comment: =E7 or E9 + E10

Comment: I dont want to take this kind of formulas, only the ones which has folder path

Comment: The problem is; when I put equal signs the formulas to be calculated, it doesnot works. gives error Application or obj defined error

Comment: Please first answer the question "what does `Debug.Print equ & np & z` return in the Immediate Window?"

Comment: If you put the debug.print equ ... it gives blank cell. empty

Comment: Please, got the main point that, without equal sign it works well

Comment: If I doesn't work with the equals sign, then it's not a valid formula.

Comment: In your code `= "=E*"`, the use of a wildcard implies you were intending to use the [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operatorr) Operator. It should be corrected to `Like  "=E*"`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting but If you're attempting to reference a range from another workbook in your formula, You're better off  using the `.Address` property from a fully qualified reference like `OtherWB.Sheet.Range.Address(External:=True)`.

Comment: @Toddleson I will give from example; actual formulas in cell are like - ='D:\Desktope\Folder1\Folder2[Excelfile.xlsm]Sheet1E30/100 to change ='C:\Desktop\Folder3\Folder4[Excelfile.xlsm]Sheet1E30/100

Comment: @BigBen it gives False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 's how I resolved the issue;

```
Sub RCaseF()
Application.DisplayAlerts =False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
wbo_n = Shee1.[A10].Value
Set wbo = Wprkbooks(wbo_n)
wbo.Activate
Set wbm = Workbooks("pathfinder.xlsm")
wbm.Activate
Sheets.Add.Name = "NewCase"
For i = 10 To Workbooks(wbo_n).Worksheets("REPORTS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
cell_str = Workbooks(wbo_n).Worksheets("REPORTS").Cells(i,137).Formula
wbm.Activate
Select Case True
Case cell_str = isBlank
Worksheets("NewCase").Cells(i,3).Value = cell_str
Case cell_str Like "=EG*" And InStr(1,cell_str, "'") =0
Worksheets("NewCase").Cells(i,3).Value = cell_str
Case cell_str Like "=SUM(EG*"
Worksheets("NewCase").Cells(i,3).Value = cell_str
Case InStr(1,cell_str, "'") >0
ospath = Sheet1.[A11].Value
nopath = Sheet1.[A17]
Selection.Replace What:=ospath, Replacement:=nopath
Worksheets("NewCase").Cells(i,3).Value = cell_str
Worksheets("NewCase").Cells(i,3).Select
Selection.Replace What:=ospath, Replacement:=nopath
End Select
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks=True
End Sub
```